# How to Save the downloaded Module

Tags: qt, qt5

I want to install and setup QT + various modules, its says there is 20GB of downloads for what I have selected.

How can I save these somewhere for use on another PC and have them installed, by using the Maintenance Tool?

Is there a storage folder the downloads are kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

20GB - that cannot be right, unless you are installing "everything". Just stick to a specific version of the framework for the compiler you want to use.

Also, no, Qt installations are not portable, thanks to a bunch of hard-coded paths. I may work if you put it example the same place it is on the other machine, I am not sure and I haven't tested this. There is also a binary patcher project, but it doesn't look to be maintained.

It would be more efficient to download the offline installer for the version you want, now **that** will work on other machines, so you can save yourself the downloading: https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.8/5.8.0/